# EF Core 2.1 Lazy loading in integration tests

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, integration-testing, automapper, lazy-loading

I've spent a couple of days hacking at this but had no joy.

I have a project with lazy loading enabled via the proxy method. The app works as expected when I run it. However, when I run our integration test suite I'm getting random failures on tests with the following error.

```
Message: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Castle.Proxies.ChangeLogProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Here's the stack trace

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 additionalInitAction, IEnumerable`1 assembliesToScan) in C:\projects\automapper-extensions-microsoft-dependencyinjectio\src\AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 69
   at Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\...\src\Web\Startup.cs:line 39
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer..ctor(IWebHostBuilder builder, IFeatureCollection featureCollection)
   at Web.IntegrationTests.Common.TestFixture`1..ctor(String relativeTargetProjectPatentDir) in C:\...\test\Web.IntegrationTests\Common\TestFixture.cs:line 111
   at Web.IntegrationTests.Common.TestFixture`1..ctor() in C:\...\test\Web.IntegrationTests\Common\TestFixture.cs:line 68
   at Web.IntegrationTests.MvcTests.StockProfileTests.StockProfilesControllerTests..ctor() in C:\...\test\Web.IntegrationTests\MvcTests\StockTests\StockControllerTests.cs:line 25
```

If I re-run the test suite I will get failures on different tests which previously passed and tests that previously failed will now pass. Also if I re-run individual tests that failed they will also pass.

One thing I've noticed is every stack trace includes the call to `AddAutoMapperClasses`. I've done some googling around this error and AutoMapper but I've not found anything.

My question is simply, has anyone seen this error or any ideas about what could be causing it?

Comment: Tell AM about you assemblies. [The docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's falling because of multiple initialization of Automapper in parallel. 
I resolved this issue with hard brute force power of xUnit:

```cs
using Xunit;

[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

Just place it anywhere in project's sources to prevent parallel test running.